# Узнать относится ли значение из одной таблицы к значению из другой?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Всем здравствуйте. 
Сайт на Wordpress. 
Есть 4 таблицы в БД Mysql которые надо как-то связать.

1. **ihc_orders** со столбцами *uid, lid, amount_value, status, create_date*
2. **users** со столбцом *id*
3. **uap_referrals** со столбцами *affiliate_id, amount, status*
4. **uap_affiliates** со столбцами *id, uid*

Значения **ihc_orders**.*uid*, **users**.*id* и **uap_affiliates**.*uid* совпадают. Например: 14, 14 и 14

Значения **uap_referrals**.*affiliate_id* и **uap_affiliates**.*id*  совпадают. Например: 12 и 12

Таблица **uap_affiliates** содержит в себе значения и 14 и 12 (возможно это как-то поможет в связке этих таблиц/столбцов).

Все эти значения относятся к одному пользователю.

Сейчас написан такой код (код хоть и кривой, но свою функцию выполняет. Всё выводит и считает в личном кабинете для каждого пользователя) В нём используются только первые две таблицы:

```html
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
    global $wpdb;
    $cur_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
    $cur_id = get_current_user_id();
    $now = time();
   
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.create_date, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.uid, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.status , " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.amount_value, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.lid, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users.id FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders, " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users WHERE " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "orders.uid=" . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users.id AND status= 'Completed'");
   
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
              $start=($result['create_date']);
              $user_uid=($result['uid']);
              $user_id=($result['id']);
              $stat=($result['status']);
              $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
              $amount=($result['amount_value']);
              $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date']));     
               
      if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==1)) {
        /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/ 
            $proc = 25;  //Процентов за всё время
            $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;  //Процентов в день
            $proc = $amount/100*$proc;  // высчитываем процент от числа
            $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;  // высчитываем процент в день от числа
            $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;  // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
            $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;  // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
            round ($amountWithPct_all);  // округляем
            round ($amountWithPct_d);    // округляем     
         
        echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
          echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
          echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
        echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br/>";
        echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
      }
     
      elseif($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==2)){
      /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
            $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
            $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
            $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
            $proc_d = $amount/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
            $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
            $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
            round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
            round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
         
        echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
          echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
          echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
        echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br/>";
        echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";     
}
      elseif ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==3)){
                /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
            $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
            $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
            $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
            $proc_d = $amount/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
            $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
            $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
            round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
            round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
         
        echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
          echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
          echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
        echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br/>";
        echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
}
      else{
        }     
  }
?>
```

Скрины БД [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как связать все эти столбцы между собой чтобы скрипт понял что это относится к одному пользователю? В соответствии с этим прибавить значение из **referrals**.*amount* к $amount (из кода выше) для пользователя к которому относятся эти столбцы. 
Ковыряю, ковыряю, а толка 0. Знаний совсем не хватает.
Заранее большое спасибо.

Получился такой код:

```html
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
 global $wpdb;
 $cur_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
 $cur_id = get_current_user_id();
 $now = time();
 
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT o.create_date, o.uid, o.status, o.amount_value, o.lid, u.id, sum(r.amount) AS referrals_amount 
 FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users AS u 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders AS o ON o.uid = u.id 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "uap_affiliates AS a ON a.uid = u.id 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "uap_referrals AS r ON r.affiliate_id = a.id 
 WHERE o.status = 'Completed' 
 GROUP BY r.affiliate_id ");
 
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $user_uid=($result['uid']);
     $user_id=($result['id']);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
     $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date']));
   $referrals_amount=($result['referrals_amount']);   
      
   if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==1)) {
  /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/  
   $proc = 25;  //Процентов за всё время
      $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;  //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc;  // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc_d;  // высчитываем процент в день от числа
    $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
   }
   
   elseif($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==2)){
   /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
   $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
     $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
       
 
}
   elseif ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==3)){
       /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
   $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
     $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
}
   else{
     }   
  } 
 /* очищаем результаты выборки */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* закрываем подключение */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

С таким кодом всё работает и считается корректно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получился такой код:

```html
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
 global $wpdb;
 $cur_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;
 $cur_id = get_current_user_id();
 $now = time();
 
 $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT o.create_date, o.uid, o.status, o.amount_value, o.lid, u.id, sum(r.amount) AS referrals_amount 
 FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "users AS u 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "ihc_orders AS o ON o.uid = u.id 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "uap_affiliates AS a ON a.uid = u.id 
 INNER JOIN " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "uap_referrals AS r ON r.affiliate_id = a.id 
 WHERE o.status = 'Completed' 
 GROUP BY r.affiliate_id ");
 
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $start=($result['create_date']);
     $user_uid=($result['uid']);
     $user_id=($result['id']);
     $stat=($result['status']);
     $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
     $amount=($result['amount_value']); 
     $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date']));
   $referrals_amount=($result['referrals_amount']);   
      
   if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==1)) {
  /* Начисляем процент для lid=1*/  
   $proc = 25;  //Процентов за всё время
      $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;  //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc;  // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc_d;  // высчитываем процент в день от числа
    $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
   }
   
   elseif($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==2)){
   /* Начисляем процент для lid=2*/
   $proc = 60; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.6*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/200*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
     $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
       
 
}
   elseif ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==3)){
       /* Начисляем процент для lid=3*/
   $proc = 89; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =0.89*$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/300*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
     $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
    
     echo "Дата оплаты: {$start}<br/>";
    echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br/>";
    echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы: {$referrals_amount} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Проценты: {$proc_d} ₽<br/>";
  echo "Бонусы + проценты: $amount_all ₽<br/>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br/><br/>";
}
   else{
     }   
  } 
 /* очищаем результаты выборки */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* закрываем подключение */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

С таким кодом всё работает и считается корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Если я все правильно понял то запрос должен правильно работать

```
SELECT o.create_date, o.uid, o.status, o.amount_value, o.lid, u.id, sum(r.amount) AS referrals_amount
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.uid = u.id
INNER JOIN affiliates AS a ON a.uid = u.id
INNER JOIN referrals AS r ON r.affiliate_id = a.id
WHERE status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY r.affiliate_id
```

У вас в массиве появится значение referrals_amount, которое будет содержать сумма referrals.amount по конкретному пользователю.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я разобралась. Проблема была в строке `WHERE status = 'Completed'` Должно быть так: `WHERE o.status = 'Completed'`